# The academically correct way to benchmark JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, jsperf

I'm currently writing a paper. In this paper, I'm going to talk about optimization of code. In my example, I'm going to distinct two arrays in JavaScript. Comparing ES5 filter vs nested for loop.

My tests using [jsPerf.com](https://jsperf.com/) went as expected. ES5 filter is 89-90% slower than a nested for loop. Similar result could be found using [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) (starting a timer, running code, stopping timer, and calculating the time taken).

All of these are great for benchmarking code. Really, they are. However, they're not academically correct. Right after the first test is done, what happens if I run a 100% CPU intensive benchmark? Test 2's results are "invalid" then.

What is the best way, the correct way, to benchmark two pieces of JavaScript code?

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-benchmarking

Comment: @robertklep I read that and all the concerns, however, if I say "I ran this code a million times and took the average time", I'm going to get bashed on that. That's not the correct way of doing it. The results would be different, if I ran the benchmarks at a 100% CPU usage.

Comment: @MortenMoulder the results will be different with different browsers, too. With different versions of browsers, as well. Which means that the results you make _now_ might be completely different few months down the line. What is your requirement for validity?

Comment: @vlaz That's true and that doesn't concern me at all. As long as I can prove one piece of code is faster right now, as of writing this paper, the future can wait.

Comment: You're asking the correct way to benchmark a piece of JS code, yet you're certain that the algorithms implemented by `Benchmark.js` aren't correct? Also, the "100% CPU usage" issue pertains to _any_ benchmarking, not just JS, so you should perhaps start with reading up on generic benchmarking "hygiene".

Comment: @robertklep Correct. The CPU usage issue can be dealt with, by checking the CPU cycles and what not in other languages. 3 guys at my work did a bachelor in performance, and they got bashed for doing it using time start, run test, time stop, and so on.

Comment: @MortenMoulder if you want to count CPU cycles, you could look at [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) (for Linux). Although I wonder if it will gain useful results for an interpreted language like JS.

Comment: @robertklep Yeah I'm not sure how I would incorporate that with this benchmark. I'm asking what the right way of doing it is, as I know people who did a bachelor on optimization, and they got "bashed" for doing it "wrong" (not the proper way academically).

Comment: @MortenMoulder if what they did was wrong, I assume that they also got to hear the correct method? Or at least what the professors would accept as being a correct method. Also, there's a binding for Node to Linux's perf counters, called [`perf-counters`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perf-counters), which would allow instruction counting from within Node.

Comment: @robertklep That's what I would assume too, but they were told basically what I already know and what I wrote here (CPU cycles and what not). Not the exact way of actually doing it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I would like to see proof on that, please. Can you show me your benchmark?

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't share a piece of code I have to use for my paper. Sorry. How would you do it?

Comment: Maybe always rely to the slowest supported browser and middle hardware configuration, always have design tresholds and tune code to meet this requirenments?

Comment: I hope you understand why I can't take you serious with that kind of attitude, @JaromandaX.

Comment: @VadimB Running this on other platforms and other browsers isn't the issue here. The issue is making sure the results are valid.

Comment: Agree, I mean we often use this technic to log timing that are exceed our treshholds. So next thing is to optimize this code only when we have sign for that. Hard to monitor everething - just react to bottlenecks. And only bottleneck occurs - we starting everething above )

Comment: @MortenMoulder - I must misunderstand what you are doing ... ES5 filter can be written with a single loop, so why you have a nested loop - and it outperforms native code 10 to 1 ... clearly I have no idea what you are actually benchmarking - so I shall remove my cruft from this question

Comment: @JaromandaX I have two arrays with strings. I need to find the duplicates in those arrays. I run a nested for loop in the first test and ES5 filter in the other test.

Comment: ok - fair enough ... as I said, I'm removing my cruft as I clearly can't say one way or the other with regards to the efficiency of your code, because yo haven't posted any

Comment: @JaromandaX I hope you understand why I can't post my code?

Comment: yes, because you've found a way to nested loop in javascript that's 10 times faster than native code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think you understand. My native code is ~10 times faster than using ES5 filters. Not the other way around. Why we're discussing this makes no sense, as that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Using Google Chrome's [Profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution) I was able to get the CPU time of my function.

Using a profiler seems like the best way to do this, as it actually uses the CPU time instead of actual time. The result should not be affected, even if my CPU runs at 100% in one of the tests.